# AllocConsole(); with GetAsyncKeyState();

Tags: c++, console

I've got some std::cout and std::cin commands between AllocConsole(); and FreeConsole();, but when I press ctrl + caps lock the console just briefly flashes by and wont cout or wait for the cin.

Is this the wrong approach to set hotkeys for bringing up the console?

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CAPITAL)){ // ctrl + caps
            AllocConsole();
            ....
            ....
            ....
            ....
            FreeConsole();
        }
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: That looks like it should be a hotkey (`RegisterHotKey`), not a poll.

Comment: You'll have to re-initialize std::cin so it is associated with the console window you created.  Try `freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL)&1

Either way, unless you put some Sleep()'s in there its just going open then close immediately.

This is definitely a job for [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: So even though I tell it to output some text and wait for my input it wont?

Comment: If you block it should work. Would love to help you out if you want a mentor.

Comment: Skype or Tox.im: http://pastebin.com/HP2xnDFz Paste expiration 1 hour. Blocking means to pause execution of a thread